# How To send burn down chart in a mail in TFS 2013

Tags: tfs, tfs-2013

Is there is any feature available in Team Foundation Server 2013 to send a burn down chart in a mail?

Answer (score 0):

No this isn't possible, you can just open and copy the image into a an e-mail yourself, but that's about it.

I'm not sure, but if you can grab the URL for the burndown image you might be able to use to Windows automation software to create an e-mail, paste in the image and send it.